# How to synchronize current from an AC and DC current

Tags: ac, dc, solar-cell, inverter, solar-energy

I'm trying to make a battery less solar grid in which energy from the solar panel will be directly given to home appliances and will be complemented by current from the grid. I'm thinking of passing the current from solar panel to an inverter and amplifying it but the problem is that the phase, frequency, etc. will have to matched with the AC current from grid otherwise many problems such as back-voltage will occur.

Comment: You need a special inverter designed for that application, the phase and frequency of the inverter is controlled by the grids phase and frequency. But if there is a power outage of the grid, the home must be isolated from the grid and the inverter should run with his own frequency. If grids power is restored, the connection of the home to the grid may be closed only if both nets are synchronized and there is no difference in phase or frequency.

Comment: Sounds like a "grid tie inverter" to me. What's wrong with the commercially available ones?